# What did Emanuel Shinwell mean by "his country"?

Tags: united-kingdom, parliament, antisemitism

On 30th of October 1956, during the Suez Canal crisis, 17 Jewish MPs voted to censure the government on a resolution which did not explicitly mention Israel[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qwtGr.gif).

[image]

Former Jewish Minister of Defence, Emanuel Shinwell who was absent from the vote, said he had

> The utmost contempt for those Jews, including British MPs who, though
>   professional Zionists, claim to see in Israel's action an offence
>   against international law. They ought to be ashamed. Jews defending
>   themselves against persecution and aggression have my full support ...
>   I was reluctant to defy party decisions but I preferred upholding my
>   country's interests."

When he says, his country's interests, what does that mean? Also in Jewish Chronicles, Jewish MPs were reminded that "The Jewish representatives in the Houses of Parliament should not allow themselves to forget their racial origins, irrespective of their political affiliations" (J.C., 16 November 1956)

What was this person then [on about](https://blogs.spectator.co.uk/2011/12/jewish-divided-loyalty-the-old-lie/) in 2011?

> Mr Halfon later commented on the matter in an article in the Jewish
>   Chronicle:
>
> ‘The subtext, of course is that Jews by nature are not loyal to the
>   country that they serve but are working for foreign powers, This has
>   been the habitual accusation of anti-Semitism throughout the ages.’

[1](https://www.jstor.org/stable/30245756)

Comment: isn't this a question for the history stack?

Comment: @dolphin_of_france Maybe – if you think so, you should vote to close as off-topic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Harold Lever](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harold_Lever,_Baron_Lever_of_Manchester) was a British MP, and so "his country" would be Britain. The same is true for [Ian Mikardo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ian_Mikardo) and [Emanuel Shinwell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manny_Shinwell).

The description of "former Jewish minister of Defence" for Manny Shinwell is a bit confusing, and would have been perhaps better as "Jewish former Minister of Defence".

Comment: OK I understand now I just couldn't align "defy party decision" with "uphold country interest" -- that just means that he doesn't believe that his party decision is in his country's interest.